# Git doesn't clone all directories

Tags: git, github

I try to clone [antlr4dart](https://github.com/tiagomazzutti/antlr4dart) repository

```
git clone https://github.com/tiagomazzutti/antlr4dart
```

but subdirectory *antlr4dart/antlr4dart-runtime* stays empty. All other files are cloned as I expected. What have I done wrong?

Thanks, Michael

Answer (score 5, accepted):

After the cloning, you have to jump into the directory:

```
cd antlr4dart
```

To get all the submodules of a directory cloned, do:

```
git submodule update --init
```

With version 1.6.5 of Git and later, you can use:

```
git clone --recursive git://github.com/foo/bar.git
```

Comment: hey, if i have to update submodules of a specific branch, what would be the command?

Answer (score 5):

You need to add (after the `git clone`):

```
cd antlr4dart
git submodule update --init
```

That gray "`antlr4dart-runtime`" folder in the GitHub repo is a **[submodule](http://git-scm.com/book/en/Git-Tools-Submodules)**, with a [gitlink entry](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16581096/6309) referring to the [SHA1 1f4b2b6](https://github.com/tiagomazzutti/antlr4dart-runtime/tree/1f4b2b6b17dbb86a61dae2b9b921526ea6bcd026) of that [submodule repo](https://github.com/tiagomazzutti/antlr4dart-runtime).

Answer (score 0):

keep in mind that folders preceded by a . don't show up. you can still access them by the cd command.